# Android: detecting snackbar dismiss or timeout in coordinator layout's behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-snackbar

I want to change a floating action button's position according to some snackbars appearing and disappearing. It goes fine with snackbars timing out by themselves, but it doesn't work with snackbars, which are manually dismissed. I want to set the position in onDependentViewRemoved in the latter case, however, with timing out snackbars it causes some problems as both onDependentViewChanged and onDependentViewRemoved are called. Therefore, I want to somehow be able to detect in onDependentViewChanged or onDependentViewRemoved if the given snackbar was dismissed or timed out. Setting the snackbar's view to the floating action button is not an option as these snackbars can appear on several fragments and not all of them have floating action buttons. I wonder if someone knows if such event/state detection in the floating action button's behaviour is possible?

That's what I have now:

```
@Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        if ((child instanceof FloatingActionMenu ||
                child instanceof FloatingActionButton) &&
                (dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout ||
                        dependency instanceof AHBottomNavigation)) {
            this.updateTranslation(parent, child, dependency);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDependentViewRemoved(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        if ((child instanceof FloatingActionMenu ||
                child instanceof FloatingActionButton) &&
                dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) {

            this.updateTranslation(parent, child, dependency);
        }
    }
```

However, as I said, the positions are messed up or even sometimes the app crashes when both methods are called (when a snackbar times out). Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour of `FloatingActionButton` is reacting to your case. Try looking into [`android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.Behavior`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.java#544) and see, why `FloatingActionButton` is reacting to the `Snackbar`.

From quickly looking into the source code, you should override:

- [`public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.java#562)
- [`public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.java#569)
- [`public void onDependentViewRemoved(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.java#582)

You could see, that all of those function invoke:

[`private void updateFabTranslationForSnackbar(CoordinatorLayout parent, final FloatingActionButton fab, boolean animationAllowed)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.java#622)

Copy the code from this function and it should work.